# exit 0 No emails were triggered

Tags: jenkins

No email was sent through Jenkins job while email security setup was done successfully and Jenkins configuration  was set too 
 the result as follows :

C:\Manar\Work\JenKins\Java Samples>exit 0 
No emails were triggered.
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's currently not clear to me what your question is. You've received a notification, but was it not what you expected? What did you expect instead? Please edit your question and add more detail. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Note: I Am working on localhost